# Multiple queries in one statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to get the following two queries into one statement in PostgreSQL.

```
select count(*) as REDEEMTOTALUSED 
from voucher 
where campaign_id='123' and redeemcount>0;

select count(*) as REDEEMTOTALUNUSED 
from voucher 
where campaign_id='123' and redeemcount=0;
```

The result should be the following.

```
REDEEMTOTALUSED | REDEEMTOTALUNUSED
1               | 9
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
    (select count(*) as REDEEMTOTALUSED 
     from voucher 
     where campaign_id='123' and redeemcount>0) AS REDEEMTOTALUSED ,
    (select count(*) as REDEEMTOTALUNUSED 
     from voucher 
     where campaign_id='123' and redeemcount=0) AS REDEEMTOTALUNUSED
```

or another way:

```
    SELECT 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN redeemcount>0 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) as REDEEMTOTALUSED ,
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN redeemcount=0 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0
           END) as REDEEMTOTALUNUSED 
    from 
       voucher 
    WHERE
       campaign_id='123'
```

Comment: It would be better, I think, to move the condition on `campaign_id` from inside the `CASE` to a `WHERE` - i.e. `FROM voucher WHERE campaign_id = '123'`

Comment: This is potentially *very* inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when redeemcount > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as REDEEMTOTALUSED,
       sum(case when redeemcount = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as REDEEMTOTALUNUSED
from voucher 
where campaign_id = '123';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(redeemcount > 0 OR NULL) AS redeemtotalused
     , count(redeemcount = 0 OR NULL) AS redeemtotalunused
FROM   voucher
WHERE  campaign_id = '123'; -- or just 123 if campaign_id is a numeric type
```

Overview of applicable techniques:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684)

Aside: unquoted identifiers are cast to **lower case** in Postgres ([Overview](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference/Data_structure_definition/Delimited_identifiers#Delimited_identifiers)). Your syntax convention is rather unhelpful in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option using [**CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html) :

```
with cte as (
             select count(*) as REDEEMTOTALUSED 
             from voucher 
             where campaign_id='123' and redeemcount>0
),cte1 as   (
             select count(*) as REDEEMTOTALUNUSED 
             from voucher 
             where campaign_id='123' and redeemcount=0
)
select REDEEMTOTALUSED
      ,REDEEMTOTALUNUSED
from
cte1,cte2
```